# How to print the head (first 10 rows) with only select variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

To print out the first 10 rows of a dataframe in R, I am using `head(data.frame, 10)`.

But this dataframe has 64 variables, and I only want to select 3 of those variables to show for my print out of the first 10 rows.

Can I use the head function to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use dplyr::select first and then run head after that in a pipe :)

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.5),
           y = rnorm(100, 30, 2),
           z = rnorm(100, 200, 20))


df %>% 
  select(x, y) %>% 
  head(., 10)
```

Comment: could also use `slice_head(n=10)` in place of `head`

Comment: Thank you so much, all of the above worked!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Might be what you're looking for :

```
# prints out the first 10 rows of the first 3 columns (or whichever you select by index
head(df[,1:3], 10)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

A base-R approach could be something like

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.5),
           y = rnorm(100, 30, 2),
           z = rnorm(100, 200, 20))

head(df[,1:2],10) #1st and 2nd columns
head(df[,c(1,3)],10) #1st and 3rd columns
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!